# Why does the visual studio debugger show the wrong value and how can I correct this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a simple program that gives me strange results in the Visual Studio debugger.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("4280.159d * 1000000 = {0}", 4280.159d * 1000000);
double D = 4280.159d * 1000000;
Console.WriteLine("D = {0}", D);
Console.WriteLine("Put a breakpoint here and look at value of D in debugger");
```

This prints out the following:

```
4280.159d * 1000000 = 4280159000
D = 4280159000
```

This output is correct but if you look at it in the debugger the value of D shows as 4280158999.9999995.

If you type the same equation in the immediate window you get the same incorrect answer.

The only way to get what seems to be the correct answer is to cast to decimal in the debugger

```
(decimal)4280.159d * 1000000
4280159000
```

The behaviour is the same in VS2010 and VS2012 and it doesn't seem to matter if it is 64bit or 32bit.
Why does it the debugger give a different result from the running code and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The debugger is correct. Printing the value out is causing the rounding.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of _floating point_.  Use `decimal`.

Comment: Welcome to floating point numbers. 4280.159 has no perfect representation as an IEEE floating point number.

Comment: @spender he's using `decimal`, not `float`. If I understand correctly decimal is base 10 rather than base 2.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal : No he's not. He's using double literals by suffixing his numbers with `d` (e.g. 4280.159d)

Comment: @spender right you are. my mistake.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 6):

The debugger shows the correct value. The `WriteLine` call is rounding up the decimal and converting it to a string so that it can be displayed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure WriteLine isn't rounding. If you change if to read Console.WriteLine("D = {0:0.##########}", D); it still reads out 4280159000.

Comment: @RonnBlack It's the implicit cast to string that does the rounding, the assignment within `WriteLine` causes that happen.